# Any way to "combine" galleries or show multiple galleries as one?

Tags: images, gallery, customization

So let's say I run a TV show blog. One day, the show releases to the public a set of 10 screencaps from an upcoming episode. I post that on my blog, either as a post with multiple images, or specifically as a "gallery" post -- either way, readers can view all the image attached to that post as a gallery.

Then, several days and several posts later, they release 10 more screencaps from that same upcoming episode. I want to make a separate post rather than bump the old one, but I also somehow want to be able to display all screencaps (20) from that particular episode in a single gallery. Or at least what would look like a single gallery.

Possible? (Preferably without NextGEN or other plugins... trying to accomplish as much as I can using WordPress' native capabilities before stacking plugins.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [the default `[gallery]` shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) there is no easy way to combine different galleries into one. You can either specify two different galleries: one of the current post and one of another post, specified by post ID:

```
[gallery]
[gallery id=42]
```

Or you can create a gallery by explicitly specifying all the *attachment* IDs:

```
[gallery include="23,39,45"]
```

Specifying multiple post IDs will not work because `gallery_shortcode()` uses `get_children()` to get the attachments, which uses `get_posts()`, which uses the standard `WP_Query` class, and this [only allows a numeric `post_parent` value](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-includes/query.php#L2131).

**However**, we can exploit the fact that there is a filter at the top of `gallery_shortcode()`, that allows plugins to override the default gallery layout. The following example checks for an `id` parameter with multiple IDs (or the special keyword `this`), gets all the attachments of these posts, and puts them in an explicit `include` attribute which is used to call the gallery function again. This allows you to combine different galleries like this: `[gallery id=this,8]`. You can extend this idea to support other attributes too.

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'wpse18689_post_gallery', 5, 2 );
function wpse18689_post_gallery( $gallery, $attr )
{
    if ( ! is_array( $attr ) || array_key_exists( 'wpse18689_passed', $attr ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    $attr['wpse18689_passed'] = true;

    if ( false !== strpos( $attr['id'], ',' ) ) {
        $id_attr = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => 'this',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        ), $attr );
        $all_attachment_ids = array();
        $post_ids = explode( ',', $id_attr['id'] );
        foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
            if ( 'this' == $post_id ) {
                $post_id = $GLOBALS['post']->ID;
            }
            $post_attachments = get_children( array(
                'post_parent' => $post_id,
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'order' => $id_attr['order'],
                'orderby' => $id_attr['orderby'],
            ), ARRAY_A );
            $all_attachment_ids = array_merge( $all_attachment_ids, array_keys( $post_attachments ) );
        }
        $attr['include'] = implode( ',', $all_attachment_ids );
        $attr['id'] = null;
    }

    return gallery_shortcode( $attr );
}
```

Comment: @Jan I was thinking that perhaps it is possible to re-attach the images to the new Post? I haven't tried this though, so don't know for sure if that would work...

Comment: @Piet: You can only attach an image to one post. This is because the "parent" post ID is stored in the `post_parent` field of the attachment, and this can only accept one value. There are some plugins that work around this, but they do it in a non-standard way, and not all other code (like the standard `[gallery]` shortcode) will work with it.

Comment: @Jan thanks for the explanation, that does indeed make sense :)

Comment: I haven't delved into things like taxonomies yet, but would it be possible to "tag" galleries in a custom taxonomy called "albums" and then somehow call an album that would essentially call all the attachment IDs of all galleries tagged for that album and display it as a single gallery?

Comment: @Chris: While washing the dishes your idea got me thinking. I now wrote a plugin that "hijacks" the default implementation to do an explicit query for the attachments of multiple posts.

Comment: Wow, great to see you got a working version of it. I'll try this out and it should suffice for what I'm trying to do. Maybe once I get some time toward the end of the month, I'll look into building off this to see if I can actually put together a manageable "album" functionality. Thanks!